# Modal Pop up doesn't load on page - Javascript

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, popup

I used a modal to create a pop up box when my page is loading.

My code works perfectly fine on my test codepen: https://codepen.io/nico3d911/pen/yjBRrK?editors=1010

But when i want to put it in my real project, basically copy pasting, I don't have any result :(

https://codepen.io/nico3d911/pen/odvmPR?editors=1011

HTML:

```
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">

    <h1>Choose your team!</h1>
    <span class="close-button" style='color:#4286f4' onclick = 'test()'>X</span>
    <span class="close-button" style='color:#e29126' onclick = 'test()'>O</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.modal {
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        transform: scale(1.1);
        transition: visibility 0s linear 0.25s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
    }
    .modal-content {
      text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        background-color: white;
        padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
        width: 24rem;
        border-radius: 0.5rem;
    }
    .close-button {
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 1.5rem;
        line-height: 1.5rem;
        cursor: pointer;
        border-radius: 100%;
        border: 2px solid lightgray;
        padding: 20px;
        margin: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
        font-size:2em;
    }
    .close-button:hover {
        border: 2px solid #3fcc64;
    }
    .show-modal {
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        transform: scale(1.0);
        transition: visibility 0s linear 0s, opacity 0.25s 0s, transform 0.25s;
    }
```

Javascript:

```
// Modal
window.onload = function(){
  toggleModal();
};

var modal = document.querySelector(".modal");

function toggleModal() {
        modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
    }


function test() {
  modal.classList.toggle("show-modal");
  player.team = 'X';
  console.log(player);
}
```

I also have an overlay on the page, but I don't think those 2 are in conflict...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi, I copy and pasted your code and I saw that the **modal's css** is missing. And you have some **html markup** in your css file.

Comment: I added the CSS! and corrected the html in CSS file. But still doesn't work.

Comment: The link to bootstrap at the head of your html it has a class named "modal" and is conflicting. If you remove or change your modal to another name, it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've copied and pasted your codepen code and saw that the css to modal was missing from the main project and you also had some html markup in your css file.

Also your modal has a class **modal** and it's conflicting with bootstrap that also have a class called **modal**. You should give your's a different name. Even with this you have to change your css because bootstrap give a `box-sizing: border-box` to all elements so it's messing with your css.